# Display a protected static website hosted on S3 within an iframe

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, iframe, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a problem I'm going absolutely crazy over, since I can't solve it now for a few weeks.
The general setup is this:

We have a frontend app, where users can register. Depending on their roles, they get to see specific content/material that is hosted in the form of static HTML/CSS/JS sites on a private S3 bucket. The idea is then to pull in those static applications into an iframe and display them within our React page.
The authorization already works in general (using CloudFront + Lambda@Edge authenticating each request to access the material). When doing a request from the frontend, when authenticated, we get back the HTML document.
Since we can't put headers into an iframe we're using a solution that preloads the document and then adds it to the iframe `srcDoc` property.
However when fetching the material, we **only** get back the HTML document, none of the styling or the images. When I remove the authentication and use the `src` property of the iframe everything works as expected. However when added authentication, only the request to the `src` page is made and no dependencies are loaded.
Is there any way to make it work in this current setup? 
If not, what's the smartest way to go about this from an app-architecture point of view? We need to have protected, external material that has a certain structure (index.html, a stylesheet and maybe some resources) within our React app.

Here is the code that I'm using in React:

```js
const MaterialView = () => {
    const [materialContent, setMaterialContent] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        const createIframe = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await axios.get(cloudfrontUrl, {
                    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('jwt')}` },
                    responseType: 'blob',
                });
                const dataURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(res.data);
                setMaterialContent(dataURL);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        };
        createIframe();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {materialContent && (
                <iframe
                    width="100%"
                    height="1000px"
                    src={courseContent}
                ></iframe>
            )}
        </div>
    );
```

The output on the page is then **just** the HTML document. So at least the connection to S3 works for that file, but not for the resources.

I would also be happy to do something where I somehow parse the received HTML and make more requests to the source for the other resources. But so far I just can't figure out how to do it properly.

Comment: Can you please provide some minimal code to allow reproduction? Do you get any Lambda@Edge logs? If not, your React frontend is preventing something, not AWS.

Comment: Hey @ErmiyaEskandary, thanks a lot for helping! Should have added in the code snippet myself before, but completely forgot. It's there now :)

Comment: Is the issue that you're only pulling e.g. index.html with credentials, and all other requests have no authentication because are included from the index.html?

Comment: Yes, sorry I never updated this. I fixed it by basically setting a cookie on the first request, so that all subsequent requests are authorized.